# Synchronous buck converter dies instantly after applying 24 V

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, over-voltage-protection

I am using an [AP63356Q](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP63356Q_AP63357Q.pdf) to step down from 24 V to 12 V. Everything works fine when the 24 V is coming from a Meanwell S-150-24 AC-DC power supply, but the buck converter got fried when I changed the power supply to RS-50-24. I measured that the Vin and Vout pins on the converter were shorted.

I've seen a 30 V spike on my multimeter when turning the RS-50-24 on, but I can't see it on my scope which shows a clear startup voltage at 24 V. I am not sure it's because of the overvoltage the converter fried

Please see my schematic below:

[image: Power filter]

VIN is connected to the RS-50-24 power supply output, so it's 24 V ideally.

D2, D3, and D4 are TVS diodes which have 31.4 V as the breakdown voltage.

Then VSUP is fed into the AP63356Q as shown below:

[image: AP63356Q]

It's identical to the reference design that is defined in the datasheet:

[image: AP63356Q reference design]

Firstly I found my input capacitor (C5) has a lower voltage rate (16 V), so I changed it to 50V X5R.  The result was the same. Fried.

I've also done some research, and it seems like an overcurrent issue, but why does the S-150-24 work fine while the RS-50-24, which has less power, has fried five AP63356Q chips?

**Update:**

1. Desoldered AP63356Q and C5.
2. Soldered 1.2K Ohms on C5 slot.
3. Turned ON RS-50-24 and scoped the VSUP.

[image: scope]

It has 2 surges which are both above the max rating of AP63356Q.  Not sure why those TVS diodes did not do anything...

Below shows S-150-24 surges.
[image: scope result S-150-24]

Comment: Try a TVS or electrolytic at the input. It's probably inrush surge.

Comment: Was the Buck output loaded during the test?

Comment: Why use a common mode filter and connect both sides to the same ground?

Comment: @tobalt Yes, it was loaded.

Comment: @bobflux I believe its intention was to filter out the common mode noise. The design needs to pass a conducted immunity test, thus the filter was added.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the advice, but the design does have three TVS diodes at the input before that filter.

Comment: What bob is trying to say is that your common mode filter is useless. It is saturated and ineffective because you conduct only through one of its windings

Comment: @tobalt Yes indeed if both sides of the common mode filter are connected to the same ground, then the noise will skip the filter through this connection and it's no longer a common mode filter... Also it'll saturate the core and do pretty much nothing. I wonder if that's could be the source of the voltage spike...

Comment: Thanks guys! That's indeed a mistake!  I am making modifications and will do test again.

Comment: @ErikZ After the filter, input to the regulator. And what type is the filter? If it's a mains style filter, it's inappropriate as mentioned.

Comment: @bobflux just fried another one...

Comment: @TimWilliams It's a DC power line filter (5500.2019).

Comment: By SCHURTER? Datasheet: https://us.schurter.com/en/datasheet/typ_FPP-02.pdf which is a 6.5A 2x1mH 0.1uF 2x2.2nF "AC Filter for PCB Mounting in Flat Housing".  It probably doesn't saturate, actually; more to the point, since one winding is shorted to GND, only leakage inductance is present, which will be a few ~uH (how much exactly, I'm not sure from the data). This component can be replaced with a single inductor of similar value, and the ceramic caps nearby do more than the filter would. An electrolytic to dampen the filter would be good, since you already have the outside TVS.

Comment: Can you desolder the dead chip and probe VCC with the scope at power-up? Another hypothesis would be the filter creating a LC resonance with the input cap, which is excited by the chip's switching frequency and causes overvoltage. Could check this with a network analyzer, or just manually apply a load resistor across C5 to draw say 100mA, and probe VSUP with a scope as you remove the resistor. You should see the ringing of the LC then. Can also use a MOSFET to switch the resistor of course...

Comment: @bobflux Please see the updates.

Comment: Nice scope shot! The TVS will catch spikes on the power supply side of the filter, but not on the buck chip side, and the LC circuit rings on the buck side of the filter. A simple fix would be to add an aluminium electrolytic cap, say 100µF, in parallel with C5. Capacitor ESR and capacitance will add damping. If you add more ceramics, they have very low ESR so you won't get damping.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for helping! The issue has been solved by moving the filter in front of everything.  I should have done that at the beginning of the troubleshooting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been solved by moving the line filter in front of "everything" and correcting its ground connections.  As the result, LC resonance is gone and both RS-50-24 and S-50-24 can power up the circuit.

Updated schematic:
[image: new schematic]

VSUP looks good as shown below:
[image: vsup scope]

Comment: Nice happy end! Well done!